# How does one replicate C++'s template based SFINAE pattern in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, sfinae

I have the following:

```
trait Runnable {
    fn run(&self);
}

struct Foo<T> {
    // Something
}

impl<T> Runnable for Foo<T>
where
    T: Send + Sync,
{
    fn run(&self) {}
}

impl<T> Runnable for Foo<T>
where
    T: Send + ?Sync,
{
    fn run(&self) {}
}
```

The compiler complains about a duplicate `impl` even though the `T` is mutually exclusive in both cases:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Runnable` for type `Foo<_>`:
  --> src/main.rs:16:1
   |
9  | / impl<T> Runnable for Foo<T>
10 | | where
11 | |     T: Send + Sync,
12 | | {
13 | |     fn run(&self) {}
14 | | }
   | |_- first implementation here
15 | 
16 | / impl<T> Runnable for Foo<T>
17 | | where
18 | |     T: Send + ?Sync,
19 | | {
20 | |     fn run(&self) {}
21 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation for `Foo<_>`
```

Comment: How is `T` mutually exclusive? `?Sync` has no effect, it is not a negative trait bound so every `T` that is valid for your first function is also valid for the second. As the compiler warning tells you "default bound relaxed for a type parameter, but this does nothing because the given bound is not a default. Only `?Sized` is supported"

Answer (score 4):

What you want is specialization:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Runnable {
    fn run(&self);
}

struct Foo<T> {
    _t: T,
}

impl<T> Runnable for Foo<T>
where
    T: Send + Sync,
{
    fn run(&self) {}
}

impl<T> Runnable for Foo<T>
where
    T: Send,
{
    default fn run(&self) {}
//  ^^^^^^^ this is the magic you need
}

fn main() {}
```

However, as of Rust 1.26.2, specialization is not stable and requires a nightly compiler.

Comment: While I agree that this solves OPs *problem*, it doesn't answer their *question*.

Comment: Like @Shepmaster said... Is there a way to do something similar on the stable compiler (maybe even if it is a lot more verbose)... I am not looking to specialize implementations, rather have separate implementations for types that have mutually exclusive trait bounds.

Comment: @ssb Mutually exclusive trait bounds don't exist in Rust.

Comment: @CodesInChaos What about `Sync` and `!Sync` (that was the OP's intent, if I understand well)

Comment: @Boiethios I think `!Sync` only exists in the context of implementing a trait (to disable a trait implemented by default) and not as a negative trait bound.